# Having stringstream with some data how to gzip it cross platform way?

Tags: c++, compression, stringstream

So we have some stringstream with somedata. With help of which cross platform library we can turn its contents into gziped  format (you would save it into file with extention .tar.gz)

Lets get into code: so I have:

```
          stringstream body;
          body << std::ifstream( path.string().c_str(), ios::binary).rdbuf();
```

Which includes shall I add, which function should I call to encode stringstream and which finction to call to turn to put that encoded data into stringstream?

BTW: is there any boost library that can encode into gzip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[boost](http://www.boost.org/).[iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) has optional built-in support for [bzip2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/bzip2.html) and [gzip](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html) compression/decompression.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too clear what you're asking.  If you mean that the
file (specified by `path`) is in gzipped format, the easiest
solution is probably to define a pipe input stream, and read it
from `gunzip < file` through that.  If you want to unzip it
within your application, some sort of filtering input streambuf
would seem in order (see boost::iostream).

And I wouldn't use a temporary `std::ifstream` in any case: you
want to verify that the open succeeded before trying to read.